# What was Dean character trying to do by killing dogs?

Tags: character, the-leftovers

The leftovers series left many questions in my mind. One of them is about *Dean*. We saw him wandering in Mapleton shooting dogs.

Why was he doing that? Was he a sort of crazy person with radical beliefs? He seemed to get crazy in final season because:

> He tried to kill Kevin and his son.

But at the time of killing dogs, and even in

> Helping Kevin kidnap Patty

he seemed to be a rational person.